# Looking for a list of Pokemon in Pokemon Outlaw

Tags: pokemon-outlaw

Been playing this hack recently and while it is pretty fun, I was wondering if there was a list of which Pokemon are obtainable. Since every time I try to Google it, the only results I end up with are YouTube playthroughs of the game.